# how to take backup of a child table with foreign key dependency in mysql using bash

Tags: mysql, backup, scripting

**Parent table** : p_id, t_id, name , salary
**Child table** : c_id, t_id , age
**key** : Child.t_id=Parent.t_id

While taking backup i would like to take pull only the matching records from Child table . How can i do it via bash script ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL 5.x

mysqldump has a `--where` option that can be used to limit/select rows to be backed up.

There isn't an option to join two tables using `--where` but you can identify which `t_id` values you want to backup and then run two mysqldumps as follows:

`mysqldump -u... -p... --where="t_id in (10,100,200,300,.....)" database_name parent_table > parent.sql`

`mysqldump -u... -p... --where="t_id in (10,100,200,300,.....)" database_name child_table > child.sql`

Once you have the `parent.sql` and `child.sql` dump files, load them into the target database and you should be good to go.

Also, note that I am assuming `t_id` column is indexed on both tables otherwise it may take a long time to dump the rows if the two tables have large number of rows.